# Getting user input in sage-python

Tags: python, sage

Sage maths gives me an easy way of launching a multi-user python scripting site for my students with a gotcha. That is, I can't figure out how to get user input into scripts.
i.e. lines like

```
guess = int(raw_input('Take a guess: '))
```

Is this not possible with sage-maths?

Answer (score 0):

Is it text only interaction? or can you use @interact?
[Sage math interact](http://wiki.sagemath.org/interact/)